# When I use "for" as a switch statement's expression, Swift returns an error. How to get around this?

Tags: swift, for-loop, switch-statement

For the following function, I use a parameter named "for". The function contains a switch statement and returns an error when I use the parameter as the statement's expression.

Code:

```
func synoynms(for: String) -> [String]? {
    switch for {
        case "swift": return synonyms["swift"]
        case "objective": return synonyms["swift"]
        case "calculate": return synonyms["swift"]
        case "create": return synonyms["swift"]
        default: return nil
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error: Synonyms.playground:25:12: error: expected expression in 'switch' statement
    switch for {
           ^
```

I think it's interpreting "for" as something else, but will I be forced to find a different parameter or is there a way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` is a reserved word, if you want to use reserved words as variable or function names you need to escape them with back-ticks.

Try this

```
switch `for` {
```

PS. You can improve this function signature by adding a variable name that is different from the label, like this

```
func synoynms(for word: String) -> [String]? {
    switch word {
```

Now `word` is the name of your variable, and calls still look like this: `synonyms(for: "cheese")`

Comment: Thank you, these are great options. As a followup, what is more common? This might be out of scope of the question, but I often see multiple options for syntax and wonder how to determine which to use.

Comment: Style is very much a matter of preference, if you search for `swift style guide` you'll find that some companies have very comprehensive guides, but in general the goal is to write explicit code that is easy to read and understand. In this specific case, using `word` gives you some context on the variable, something that the name `for` doesn't do.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Cheers